# Is it possible to make ethereum private by default like how monero has it?

Tags: erc-20, privacy, anonymity, zksnark, monero

How would ethereum be made private and anonymous by default like how monero has it? Is it possible to turn an token into a fully private anonymous token by default?

Comment: It is possible with a major rewriting in the code, but I don't think it will get done since it will not comply with money laundering rules. Creators of monero may be sued by some authority for facilitating money laundering. It is not safe to make a currency anonymous, you could end up in jail. The authority will show up when they believe the thing has became a problem, check about Napster and Megaupload for examples.

Comment: also true anonymity can't be reached with blockchain by definition, because the ledger is `open` and can be accessed publicly

Comment: Your right it would be illegal to keep your transactions private. Best to show what your doing with your crypto coins. We wouldn't want anyone funneling money to bad organizations.